# what is the overhead of DATE or DATE_FORMAT in WHERE clause?

Tags: php, mysql

`event_date` is of type `DATETIME` and `$date` = `'2014-11-07'`

I could run the query

```
$this->Select(" * FROM events WHERE DATE(event_date) = ?",
                 array($date));
```

or

```
$this->Select(
      " * FROM events WHERE DATE_FORMAT(event_date,'%Y-%m-%d') = ?",
                 array($date));
```

But I'm wandering would that cause it to perform the date operation every row?

Perhaps it would be better to use

```
$this->Select(" * FROM events WHERE event_date = ?",
                 array($date. ' 00:00:00'));
```

instead?

Comment: Do all your event_date rows have 00:00:00 as time?

Comment: @michael sorry yes. ony the date is being stored, I didn't architect this db :/

Comment: Then I'd go with the 3rd option. Did you make benchmark tests on that? Would be interessting

Comment: @michael I will do, I'll copy you in when I have this done, thanks

Comment: thank you! I have quite similar queries, if I find something on that, I'll post it

Comment: @michael posted some benchmarks below, doesn't seem to be worth loosing sleep over

Comment: Thank you very much. Not much difference, but still interesting. I need to do this with nearly a million rows, so the difference might be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Showing benchmarks for the above question:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE date(event_date) ='2014-11-07' limit 0,10000;
--Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 10,000 total, Query took 0.0087 sec)

SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE date_format(event_date,'%Y-%m-%d') ='2014-11-07' limit 0,10000;
--Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 10,000 total, Query took 0.0119 sec)

SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE event_date   ='2014-11-07 00:00:00' limit 0,10000;
--Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 10,000 total, Query took 0.0076 sec)
```

outputs as shown in phpmyadmin